# TSQL SUM column with and without where in same procedure

Tags: sql-server, sum, union

I have to SUM some data from a column, group by date, and then I need another sum but with a WHERE statement on the same column.

Example of myTable:

```
item | col1 | insertDate
-------------------------
1    | 10   | 01/01/2015
2    | 30   | 01/01/2015
3    | 20   | 01/01/2015
1    | 50   | 02/01/2015
3    | 20   | 02/01/2015
1    | 10   | 03/01/2015
2    | 30   | 03/01/2015
1    | 20   | 04/01/2015
```

The result I need is:

```
date       | sum(col1) | sum(col1) where item = 1
01/01/2015 | 60        | 10
02/01/2015 | 70        | 50
03/01/2015 | 40        | 10
04/01/2015 | 20        | 20
```

I've done this procedure:

```
select sum(col1) as tot, 0 as totItem, 
    CAST(insertDate AS date) as data
from myTable 
where (CAST(insertDate AS date) >= @start) 
    AND (CAST(insertDate AS date) <= @end)
group by CAST(insertDate AS date)
union
select  0 as tot, sum(col1) as totItem,
    CAST(insertDate AS date) as data
from myTable  
where (item = @item) 
    and (CAST(insertDate AS date) >= @start) 
    AND (CAST(insertDate AS date) <= @end)
group by CAST(insertDate AS date)
order by data
```

What I have is almost what I want but obviously I have 2 rows for each SELECT

```
date       | sum(col1) | sum(col1) where item = 1
01/01/2015 | 60        | 0
01/01/2015 | 0         | 10
02/01/2015 | 70        | 0
02/01/2015 | 0         | 50
etc...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statements instead of two different sums, like this:

```
Select InsertDate
    , Sum(Col1) as Sum_allCol1
    , Sum(case when item = 1 then col1 else 0 end) as Sum_item1
from MyTable
group by InsertDate
```

Alternatively, if you are attached to your current syntax, you can replace your `union` with a `join`:

```
Select distinct a.Data, a.Tot, b.TotItem1 
from
    (select sum(col1) as tot, 
    CAST(insertDate AS date) as data
    from myTable where (CAST(insertDate AS date) >= @start) AND (CAST(insertDate AS date) <= @end)
    group by CAST(insertDate AS date)
    ) a

LEFT JOIN

    (select sum(col1) as totItem1,
    CAST(insertDate AS date) as data
    from myTable  where (item = @item) and (CAST(insertDate AS date) >= @start) AND (CAST(insertDate AS date) <= @end)
    group by CAST(insertDate AS date)
    ) b
on a.Data = b.Data
```

Comment: Neat and easy! The first solution works perfectly. Thank

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `case` statement inside a `sum()` function

```
SELECT
    SUM(col1) sumall,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN item = 1 THEN col1
           ELSE 0
        END) sumitem1
    insertDate
    FROM myTable
GROUP BY insertDate
```